# I'm trying to write a query that will check if a policy has a 0 dated records or not

Tags: sql

i've a large set of data in a table that holds policy number and date that was modified. each policy should have a 0. how do i check if a policy has a 0 record or not/how do i check which policy doesn't have a 0 record. Thanks

```
policy  date
123546980   0
123546980   19950520
123546981   0
123546981   19950520
123546981   19950521
123546982   19950521
123546983   19950521
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Your "date" looks more like an integer, not like a real date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all policies that have a `0`:

```
select policy
from your_table
group by policy
having min(date) = 0
```

And to get the others you can just use  `<>` instead of `=` in your `having` clause.

You can combine and get all like this

```
select policy, 
       case when min(date) = 0 
            then 'OK'
            else 'FAIL'
       end as policy_status
from your_table
group by policy
```

Comment: select distinct policy from your_table where date = 0?

Comment: Yes works for the first case but does not for the other case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what i was looking for